# Benchmarks for Sniper Simulator

Tags: 20.04

I followed the installation process of the official website to install and compile, but I encountered the problem shown in the figure.

[image]

Comment: You did set the BENCHMARKS_ROOT environment variable correctly, as far as I can see. I guess the error message has it wrong, and your actual problem is the Python program not being executable. From the `benchmark` directory, try `chmod +x tools/python/env_setup_bm.py`, then try the `make` again.

Comment: In your first command, you used `/path/to/sniper... `something. You must have copied and pasted that command from the website without thinking. You need to replace `/path/to...` by the _actual path on your system_ to the `sniper...` resource, probably something starting with `/home/junyu2/`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help